# How to disable doc generating for type definitions in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, typespec

For example I have a module like

```
defmodule Foo do
  @type bar :: string
end
```

But I don't want to generate doc for `bar` because it's meant to use internal implementation.

Comment: If it's internal, how about declaring a private type with `@typep`? `@typep` types won't show up in the documentation.

Comment: Hmm--wasn't aware of `@typep`  Good to know about.

Comment: @Dogbert It works. Can you post it as an answer? So that I can accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `@typedoc` for types like `@doc` for functions, but unlike `@doc false`, `@typedoc false` doesn't seem to hide the type from the documentation. Since this is for internal use, I'm assuming you don't want to export it out of the module either, so you can use `@typep` to declare it private, which will also remove it from the documentation:

```
defmodule Foo do
  @typep bar :: string
end
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe that you can use the flag

```
@doc false
```

on top of the code you dont want docs for.
As shown in the docs:
[image]

Comment: `@doc false` has no effect on typespecs (at least according to @dogbert :) )

Comment: My bad, I wasn't entirely sure so I thought I might put in a suggestion. Thanks for the clarification